# Splitting an int after a value in Java

Tags: java

Sorry - I'm a beginner: is there a neat way in Java to do the following:

Anything up to 100 (the first 100) I want to multiply by 5 and the rest (100+) by 2

e.g.

```
25: (25*5) = 125
50: (50*5) = 250
100: (100*5) = 500
125: (100*5)+(25*2) = 550
150: (100*5)+(50*2) = 600
```

etc..

Is there a method in Java to split the number after 100? 
Thanks

Comment: Use a if-loop, that's basic programming.

Comment: Hint: `if (n <= 100) { return something; } else { return somethingElse; }`

Comment: @Dominique "if-loop"? Never heard of that basic programming concept before.

Comment: @byxor: seen your hint you seem to understand what I mean :-)

Comment: @Dominique Yes, but it's not a loop.

Comment: use the `%` modulo operator to solve this. `125%100=25` for example. it gives you whatever is left from the calculation

Comment: @XtremeBaumer 201%100 = 1. Probably not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement something like that...

```
public int someMethodName(int value)
{
  int splittingValue = 100;

  if(value > splittingValue)
  {
    return splittingValue * 5 + (value - splittingValue) * 2;
  }
  else {
    return value * 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method with a little use of `Math` should do:

```
public int calculate(int n) {
    return Math.min(n, 100) * 5 + Math.max(n - 100, 0) * 2;
}

public void test() {
    int[] test = new int[]{25, 50, 100, 125, 150, 5000};
    for (int n : test) {
        System.out.println("" + n + ":" + calculate(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how the `calculate` function is short, but the usage of max/min to implement the logic looks bizarre to me. Why have you chosen to do this?

Comment: @byxor - The first part `Math.min(n, 100)` extracts the part of the number that is `<= 100` as OP requires. The `Math.max(n - 100, 0)` extracts the rest of it after `100` is subtracted (but stopping it from going negative).

Comment: I was wondering why you chose a solution that's subjectively harder to read, not how it works. Oh well, at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way :

```
public int callthismethod(int x){
    return (x>100)?(((x%100)*2)+500):(5*x);
}
```